# Docker compose - Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I have the following issue. I have two spring boot micro services (1.5.8 ver), a configuration service and a discovery service. 
When I run them locally the services are starting and communicating successfully.

Now when I start this two services using a docker compose file I get the following error:

```
 Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
discovery-svc    | WARN 24 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_DISCOVERY/6c4a9f118423:discovery - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
discovery-svc    | 
discovery-svc    | com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:807) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    | 
discovery-svc    | 2017-12-20 15:19:00.314  WARN 24 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator
discovery-svc    | 
discovery-svc    | com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:807) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar!/:1.7.0]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
discovery-svc    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

I have the following files:
docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '3.4'
services:
    config-svc:
      image: "config-img"
      container_name: config-svc
      build:
        context: ../config
        dockerfile: docker/config.dockerfile
      expose:
        - "8888"    
    discovery-svc:
      image: "discovery-img"
      container_name: discovery-svc
      build:
        context: ../discovery
        dockerfile: docker/discovery.dockerfile
      depends_on:
        - config-svc
      links:
        - config-svc:config-svc 
      entrypoint: sh -c '/tmp/wait-for config-svc:8888 && java -jar discovery.jar'
      expose:
        - "8761"
```

Discovery service: bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery
  cloud:
    config:
       uri: http://config-svc:8888
  profiles:
    active: docker
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Configuration service: bootstrap.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  application:
    name: config
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: ${user.dir}/src/main/resources/configs
  profiles:
    active:
    - native
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

discovery.docker.properties

```
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery-svc:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.hostname=discovery-svc
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

I have tried many things but with no luck. 
Can anyone suggest anything?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997711/eurekaserver-com-netflix-discovery-shared-transport-transportexception-cannot-e/63006904#63006904

Answer (score 0):

are you has been try set network each service ?
so, service `config-svc` and service `discovery-svc` communication through same network. try setup driver to `bridge` as follow

`version: '3.4'
services:
    config-svc:
      image: "config-img"
      container_name: config-svc
      build:
        context: ../config
        dockerfile: docker/config.dockerfile
      expose:
        - "8888"

      networks:
            - app-network
    discovery-svc:
      image: "discovery-img"
      container_name: discovery-svc
      build:
        context: ../discovery
        dockerfile: docker/discovery.dockerfile
      depends_on:
        - config-svc
      links:
        - config-svc:config-svc 
      entrypoint: sh -c '/tmp/wait-for config-svc:8888 && java -jar discovery.jar'
      expose:
        - "8761"
      networks:
            - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
      driver: brige`

reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. The problem was in the configuration service in the bootstrap.yml file the property value of spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations must be fixed to classpath:configs. Now it's working fine.

Thanks for your reply