# EurekaServer com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server on Docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Eureka server not working on Docker compose

Here is the docker-compose for the Eureka server and config server

```
version: '3'
services:
    fetebird-eurekaservice:
        container_name: FeteBird-EurekaService
        build:
            context: ../../Eureka-Service-Registry/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: fetebird/eurekaservice
        ports:
            - "8761:8761"
        networks:
            - spring-cloud-network
        volumes:
            - ./fetebird-eurekaservice/data:/data
        logging:
            driver: json-file
    
    fetebird-configserver:
        container_name: FeteBird-ConfigServer
        build:
            context: ../../FeteBird-ConfigServer
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: fetebird/configserver
        ports:
            - "8085:8085"
        networks:
            - spring-cloud-network
        volumes:
            - ./fetebird-configserver/data:/data
        logging:
            driver: json-file        

networks:
    spring-cloud-network:
        driver: bridge
```

I tried with the expose command as well but no luck

## Eureka server docker file

```
FROM openjdk:14

WORKDIR /fetebird-eurekaservice/service

ADD build/libs/fete-bird-eureka-service-registry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar fete-bird-eureka-service-registry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "fete-bird-eureka-service-registry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

## Config server Client Docker file

```
FROM openjdk:14

WORKDIR /fetebird-eurekaservice/service

ADD build/libs/fete-bird-configuration-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar fete-bird-configuration-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "fete-bird-configuration-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

## Config Server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class FeteBirdEurekaServiceRegistryApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FeteBirdEurekaServiceRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

## Configuration of Eureka server

## application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

## bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: CONFIG-SERVER
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/config
```

## Config Server

server:
port: 8085

## Discovery Server Access

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

**Errors**

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar!/:1.9.21]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar!/:1.9.21]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar!/:1.9.21]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar!/:1.9.21]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar!/:1.9.21]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:857) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar!/:1.9.21]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar!/:1.9.21]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
FeteBird-ConfigServer     | 
FeteBird-ConfigServer     | 2020-07-20 14:30:19.268  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator
```

Comment: Please provide your Configserver's classes' contents.

Comment: Are they deployed successfully on localhost (without Docker)?

Comment: Are you using **ConfigFirst** or **EurekaFirst**? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1075#issuecomment-407524966

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar - I am using EurekaFirst(Discovery first)

Comment: @k-wasilewski Yes its deployed successfully on localhost and working fine in the local environment.

Comment: @k-wasilewski added the Eureka server code.

Comment: @SanJaisy I believe, you got your answer. You're heading in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka
```

It is pointing to localhost and Eureka is no longer running on localhost, localhost in this case is the individual containers. The containers are linked together so you can just change this to

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://fetebird-eurekaservice:8761/eureka/
    instance:
      hostname: fetebird-eurekaservice
```

Each docker file

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "fete-bird-configuration-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"] fetebird-eurekaservice
```

Docker compose file (Add links and depends_on)

```
fetebird-configserver:
        container_name: FeteBird-ConfigServer
        build:
            context: ../../FeteBird-ConfigServer
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: fetebird/configserver
        ports:
            - "8085:8085"
        links:
            - fetebird-eurekaservice
        depends_on:
            - fetebird-eurekaservice
        networks:
            - spring-cloud-network
        volumes:
            - ./fetebird-configserver/data:/data
        logging:
            driver: json-file
```

Reference - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2442

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by OP's answer: Eureka is no longer running on localhost, localhost in this case is the individual containers.

I'm here to introduce two addtional solutions:

### Solution 1. Using [docker environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment)

Dev environment (in application.properties):

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Docker environment (override defaultZone settings in `docker-compose.yml` file):

```
myservice:
    container_name: myservice
    environment:
      eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone: http://<your-eureka-service-name>:8761/eureka
```

This will override `application.properties` or `application.yml` values.

If you'd like to override a bunch stuff in docker environment like jdbc connection, you can use [`SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config) (spring will read it as it is embedded in an environment variable or system property):

```
myservice:
    container_name: myservice
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql": "//jdbc:mysql:3306/mydb",
        "spring.datasource.username": "username",
        "spring.datasource.password": "password",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto": "update",
        "eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone": "http://<your-eureka-service-name>:8761/eureka"
        }'
```

### Solution 2. Setting up different [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles):

Step one, prepare two versions of `application.properties`, if you prefer `application.yml`, your choise:

`application-default.properties` for dev environment:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

`application-docker.properties` for docker environment:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone = http://<your-eureka-service-name>:8761/eureka
```

Step two (docker-compose file):

```
myservice:
    container_name: myservice
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker
```

By setting up [SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.properties-and-configuration.set-active-spring-profiles) to docker, it will load `application-docker.properties` as active profiles.

References:

1. [Spring Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)
2. [Spring Environment-Specific Properties File](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#2-environment-specific-properties-file)
3. [How to load the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE value in the client service dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565706/how-to-load-the-spring-profiles-active-value-in-the-client-service-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

It is a common mistake that sometimes "we" forget to close other eureka servers which makes client applications confused about which server to register to.
I would therefore recommend anyone facing the same problem to always ensure that there is only one Eureka server running for your application irrespective of which one you are running (locally or docker).

Also if you are using Kubernetes, ensure that all clusters are not running(if you are using Kube Forwarder, stop all the resources if you are running the local client. The same applies to when you are running your images, ensure that the eureka server is not running in your terminal other than the image)